# TypeError: .map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'am making a little To-Do app to learn more about ReactJS and React Hooks.
The problem is that i don't understand what is wrong with the `list.map()` that i'am using. It keeps telling me that its not a function. But i don't see how im using it as a function in the first place?

I have been look all over google to see what i'm doing wrong. i have tried changing my code in multiple ways but i can't seem to figure out what is wrong. As soon as i click my "Submit" button, it crashes and gives me the `TypeError: list.map is not a function` error.

```
function ToDoList() {
  const [list, setlist] = useState(["Test 1", "Test 2"]);
  const [newItem, setnewItem] = useState("");

  const handleChange = e => {
    setnewItem(e.target.value);
    console.log(newItem);
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    setlist(...list, newItem);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={handleChange} />
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
      <ul>
        {list.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppTitle />
      <ToDoList />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'am trying to add the `newItem` to the `list` and render the list through .map().
When i start the app, the "Test 1" and "Test 2" Render, but adding to the list and rerendering it crashes it.

Comment: If `list.map` is not a function, then `list` is not a list.

Comment: Oooh, so its basically telling me i broke the list with my handleSubmit function? That explains Dacre Denny's answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason for this runtime error is that `handleSubmit()` is updating the `list` state to a non-array type:

```
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    /* 
    The list is spread into the arguments of setlist() meaning that state
    is updated to the first value of the list array
    */ 
    setlist(...list, newItem);
  };
```

When `handleSubmit()` is therefore called, the `list` state value is no longer an array which in turn means that `list.map()` no longer defined, hence the error:

> ".map() is not a function".

If you change the following section of code in your component, this will ensure that `list` is updated as a new array (where the value of "newItem" is appended to the end of that new array):

```
  const handleSubmit = () => {

    /* 
    Update the list state to a new array, with newItem appended to the
    end of it. This ensures the list state remains as an array type,
    ensuring the list.map() is defined 
    */
    setlist([...list, newItem]);
  };
```

Comment: Wow, thankyou so much! That fixed it! :) I never would have guessed that. Is there a reason why it gives me that specific error then though? Why is it telling me its not a function?

Comment: @iLoveSpicyNoodles you're welcome - just updated the answer. Does that help? :)

Comment: Yes that totally answered my question! :) Thankyou so much for the help and for teaching me what i did wrong :)

Comment: @iLoveSpicyNoodles you're welcome! All the best with your project :)